# Describe geometrically what the linear transformation does.

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the linear transformation $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with: 
$T:\begin{bmatrix} 1  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}\mapsto\begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$
and $T:\begin{bmatrix} 0  \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}\mapsto\begin{bmatrix} -1  \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Provided that this transformation corresponds to the rotation clockwise by 90 degrees. (It sends $(x,y)$ to $(-y,x)$). Describe geometrically what the linear transformation S does.

I'm just confused what to add to the geometric description since it was provided that it was a rotation counterclockwise by 90 degrees. It sounds to me very similar to a rotation about the origin from geometry?

Comment: please use [Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  to edit your question, in order to have good mathematical formulation.

Comment: Is $S$ a different application or is it just a typo?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you consider a general point $(a,b)$ then $T(a,b)=(-b,a)$. This means that the only fixed point is the origin. So the geometric interpretation as you said is a rotation of 90 degrees with center in the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Your intuition is correct, but you should think about why, or how the conclusion that this was a rotation by 90 degrees was reached.

A linear map is defined by what it does to the basis vectors, so when they tell you that T acts on the first basis by doing nothing, and the second by swapping input spots and adding a sign, you can tell what it would do to any input you give it, like an ellipse or some other shape.